# Linear transformation of a binomial random variable?

Tags: probability, distributions, binomial-distribution

Let $X$ be a binomial random variable with parameters $n$ and $p$. Next, let:

$$
Y = aX + b
$$

I know that:

$$
\mathbb{E}[Y] = \mathbb{E}[aX+b] = a\mathbb{E}[X] + b = anp + b \\
\text{Var}(Y) = \text{Var}(aX+b) = a^2 \text{Var}(X) = a^2np(1-p)
$$

But how is $Y$ distributed?

Comment: $Y$ is *never* a binomial random variable unless $b=n$ and $a=-1$ or $b=0$ and $a=1.$ This suggests you aren't using terms like "binomial" in a standard way.

Comment: Edited to ask about this instead.

Comment: The parameters question doesn't need to be asked, because you exhibit them as $(n,p,a,b).$

Comment: As far as "how is $Y$ distributed" goes, since it can have at most $n+1$ distinct values you need to specify its probability mass function or the equivalent.  Have you tried to do that? What might be the obstacle to writing it down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try one example and you will find it does not follow a simple form. For example, a `X ~ binomail(1, .5)` distribution, so the number of successes after one try with 50% probability. That's either one or zero. Now what distribution does `aX + b` follow? It's either `a` or `a + b`, both with 50% probability. There is, as far as I know, no simple formula or name for the resulting family of distibutions, it's definitely not binomial. Perhaps you can call them "linear transformations of binomail distributions".

*EDIT based on comment by whuber:*

That said, it's not to hard to write out a formula for the probability mass function,

$$
\mathbb{P}(Y = y) = \mathbb{P}(a \cdot X +b=y)
$$

and then just plugin the probability mass function for $X$ after inverting the equation.